# I just read news that Antarctica had set a new record high temperature, above 18 °C. How can this be the case if it is currently winter there?

Tags: climate-change, climate, temperature, antarctica

Currently it is winter in Antarctica. According to news I read, Antarctica has set a new record high temperature, above 18 °C. How did this temperature records occur?

Comment: What news? What publication/media?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I agree it should be linked in the question, but luckily it's now in [Jean-Marie Prival's answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/22479/6031). The original news was from 2020, [here's a photo](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/22491/6031).

Comment: Hint: Read it again half a year from now ;)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You just read the news too fast. WMO [announced](https://public.wmo.int/en/media/press-release/wmo-verifies-one-temperature-record-antarctic-continent-and-rejects-another) that, after evaluation by a committee, they have validated the 18.3°C temperature recorded *in February* (i.e., in summer) last year:

> GENEVA, 1 July 2021 (WMO) - The World Meteorological Organization
> (WMO) has recognized a new record high temperature for the Antarctic
> continent of 18.3° Celsius on 6 February 2020 at the Esperanza station
> (Argentina).

Comment: I initially read WMO as WHO, and was very confused as to why WHO were measuring Antarctic temperatures!

Comment: antartica has a fever - WHO intervenes?

Comment: Who was measuring the antarctic?

Comment: I would also add, "winter", "summer", and so on, are seasons, not thermal or climate events. What is "winter" on Mars? Or on Venus? Or Mercury? Or Pluto?

Comment: @C.M. “Winter: the coldest season of the year…” - sounds pretty thermal to me!

Comment: @C. M. Mars also has seasons and much like earth you generally have the coldest days being in winter and the warmest days in summer.  If 18 degrees actually occurred during Antarctica's winter we would be in serious trouble. Venus has the thick atmosphere but it wouldn't have seasons because like Mercury, no tilt.  Pluto is too far away to matter.

Comment: @Tim: That does not mean every day has to be more cold than any day during 'summer'. We can, and do, have days in winter that are warmer than some days in summer, and vice versa. The assumption that 'winter' _must_ be colder (than 'summer', for instance) is the error in logic that I am pointing out.

Comment: @C.M. I am not aware of any location having its hottest temperature in winter. There being hotter days in winter than some days in summer (perhaps? I don’t even know that that’s true!) is irrelevant when talking about highs + lows. But winter must, by definition, be colder than summer.

Comment: @eps: Correct. Seasons are the result of various factors: orbit and location within the orbit, axial tilt and rotation, etc. But as I said in my other comment, that was not my point. The point is that the assumptions made creates ambiguity, logical fallacies, and other issues. There is also missing information. "Record high" could mean "Record high _for normal temperatures_", and even further by "for this season" or "for the date given". I am not suggesting/debating/whatever that 18C would not be "bad mojo" in the fully assumed context, only that the context _IS_ "assumed".

Comment: @Tim I've just asked [Are there some places near the equator that are hottest in their winter and some that are hottest in their summer? Is there a map of this?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/22492/6031)

Comment: @uhoh seasons don’t really exist near the equator, at least not in the same way.

Comment: @Tim they are still *well defined* and bounded by the equinoxes, independent of meteorological conditions. It can still be Tuesday even people around you don't use a calendar. So I've just asked [Where can I ask “Do they use seasons in Ecuador?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367114/303080)

Comment: @uhoh given that seasons are defined by “weather, ecology and daylight hours”, I’m not sure that’s exactly true… seasons do exist there, but it’s normally rainy / dry. There they’re defined by rain, rather than temperature, so there isn’t a “cold season” which could have a hottest temperature - but I’m just repeating what the answer to your question says now!

Comment: @Tim disagree *because I'm a nerd* and not a practical person; first day of spring happens on the "Spring Equinox" which is really the southward or autumnal (sic) equinox in the southern hemisphere, and northward or vernal in the northern hemisphere. (should have said "equinoxes *and solstices*" in the previous comment)

Comment: @uhoh I think I understand the confusion. The definition involving the the equinox is the *astronomical* definition. I’ve been focusing on the *meteorological* definition! In the U.K., by the Met Office, spring is defined as 1st March - 31 May! https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/learn-about/weather/seasons/spring/when-does-spring-start. In countries close to the equator, obviously that meteorological definition wouldn’t be used; but the astronomical definition is not exactly relevant when discussing climate / weather. But I will concede you are *technically correct* :D

Comment: @Tim ya star gazers who also read about it have astronomical seasons drilled into their heads from an early age no matter where they live. I grew up mid-latitudes and live near one of the tropic lines and when the Sun is directly overhead my brain fries as much from the disappearance of my own shadow as much as it does from the heat. And of course we do have an incredibly active and noticeable "[typhoon season](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/21296/6031)".

Answer (score 6):

Supplemental to [Jean-Marie Prival's answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/22479/6031):

The February 2020 event was already discussed here in a question posted the same day this went public: [What is the second thermometer in the image from the Esperanza Antarctic temperature record?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19145/6031)

> [twitter.com](https://twitter.com/SMN_Argentina/status/1225455484259442691)
> [wmo.int](https://public.wmo.int/en/media/news/new-record-antarctic-continent-reported)
> [bloomberg.com](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-02-07/it-s-t-shirt-weather-in-antarctica-as-temperature-breaks-record)
> [nytimes.com](https://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2020/02/07/world/europe/ap-eu-switzerland-un-antarctica.html?searchResultPosition=1)
> [theguardian.com](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/feb/07/antarctica-logs-hottest-temperature-on-record-with-a-reading-of-183c)
>
> The tweet contained an image of a literal analogue thermometer which did show the 18.3°C... but curiously enough, also *another* thermometer showing merely 10.0°C.
>
> [image: The image tweeted by SMN Argentina]

The answer to that question is that this pair forms a wet-dry bulb system for measuring humidity.