# Is the current tropical depression headed towards Taiwan unusually early for the season? (April 7, 2022 at 4.0N 148.0E)

Tags: meteorology, climate-change, climate, tropical-cyclone

Taiwan's [Central Weather Bureau's Current Western North Pacific Tropical Cyclones page](https://www.cwb.gov.tw/V8/E/P/Typhoon/TY_NEWS.html) shows a tropical depression with the following information:

> TROPICAL DEPRESSION
>
> TD02
>
> Position 061800Z at 4.0N 148.0E, Movement: W 4km/hr. Minimum pressure 1002 hpa, Max sustained winds near center 15 meter per second, Gusts 23 meter per second.

and the map shows it headed straight for Taiwan "as usual" :-)

- [Why do 30% of all typhoons in the western north pacific (WNP) affect Taiwan?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/21296/6031)

**Question:** Is the current (April 7, 2022 at 4.0N 148.0E) tropical depression headed towards Taiwan unusually early for the season?

If so, is this a significantly early event, is it too soon to tell, or does everything seem to happen more quickly the older I get

A nontechnical source [When is Typhyoon Season in Taiwan? – A Guide to Surviving Taiwanese Typhyoons](https://biglittleisland.com/when-is-typhoon-season-in-taiwan/) says:

> And remember, **the typhoon season starts as early as May** and can last till November. That means for at least half of the year, people in Taiwan have to live in fear of a major typhoon.

---

[image: Taiwan's Central Weather Bureau tropical depression map, 2022-04-06, TD02; Position 061800Z at 4.0N 148.0E]

**above:** Taiwan's Central Weather Bureau tropical depression map, 2022-04-06, TD02; Position 061800Z at 4.0N 148.0E

Comment: "*does everything seem to happen more quickly the older I get*" - most definitely!!

Comment: "*for at least half of the year, people in Taiwan have to live in fear of a major typhoon*" - mmm, Taiwan must lie within typhoon alley.

Comment: @Fred along with the Earthquakes and regular airspace incursions, there's never a dull moment! :-)

Comment: One positive about all of that, ... at least you know you're alive ;-)

Comment: @Fred any further thoughts?

Comment: From personal observation, when weather services state that a typhoon (or similar) session starts and ends in particular months of the year it's usually a statement of a "typical" or average occurrence. Within the normal variability of weather, start & end times of a session can vary,  as can the number of typhoons in a session & their strengths. A two to four week difference in start or end times every, "now & again", might not be anomalous but six to eight weeks would appear to be, as would a persistent occurrence of such changes. ...

Comment: ... When that starts to happen it would be fair to ask whether the changes are due to anthopogenic climate change.